# Is this a real analytic function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $S$ be any subset of natural numbers. Is the function
$$
f(x) = \prod_{m \in S} (1 - \frac{x^2}{m^2})
$$
a real analytic function? If $S$ is finite, then it is clear. But when $S$ is infinite I wasn't sure.
Any explanation is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: By the way, when $S$ is all the positive integers, you can relate the product to the sine function using [the fact](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler_Formula_for_Sine_Function/Complex_Numbers) that $\sin z = z \prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{z^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)$.

Comment: It is holomorphic and hence real analytic. To show that, convince yourself for any $R > 0$, the convergence is uniform over the open disk $\{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z| < R \}$. By a corollary of [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem) (see the section about uniform limits there), $f$ is holomorphic over the disk. Since $R$ is arbitrary, $f$ is entire.